# File Upload Validator always show error message

Tags: asp.net, controls

I add asp.net file upload control as follows:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="filesFileUpload" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="file types not supported"
ValidationExpression="\.(zip|rar|jpg|gif|png|eps|ai|psd|pdf)$" ControlToValidate="filesFileUpload"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

And always when I upload file that match the reg expression it show the error. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression checks for a single dot, followed by one of the extensions, all the way to the end of the string. You need to match the rest of the the filename (`.+` matches one or more characters , `^` mean start of string):

```
ValidationExpression="^.+\.(zip|rar|jpg|gif|png|eps|ai|psd|pdf)$"
```

See [this](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) handy cheat sheet.

Comment: thnaks 
i used the following and it work good 
ValidationExpression="(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$"